# HTACCESS Forward traffic from temporary domain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, temporary

I have two working domains on the same server.

How can I forward all traffic to all files on the old temporary domain to the new correct domain?
Seems like this might be an SEO issue?
But, since the temporary testing domain isn't registered, would it even be crawled?
Is this even a problem?

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Force to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thecorrectdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.thecorrectdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
```

The incorrect domain is the setup that we used for testing, before we pointed the domain name to the new server.
The second is the correct domain.

The incorrect testing domain looks like:
http://1234.hostingcompany.com/~username/index.php

The intended correct domain looks like:
http://thecorrectdomain.com/index.php

Or is this something that the hosting company has to do at their level?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `hostingcompany` supports .htaccess. You create a .htaccess in `http://1234.hostingcompany.com/~username/` which contains something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

#might not be necessary
RewriteBase /~username

RewriteRule .* http://thecorrectdomain.com/$0 [R=301]
```

PS while testing use 302, instead of 301.